# FragmentManager on error

Tags: android, android-fragments

i had a problem here. 
i will import:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
```

and a function:

```
public void replaceFragmentContent(Fragment fragment) {
    if (fragment != null) {
        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        transaction.setTransition(transaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        transaction.replace(R.id.mainContent,fragment);
        transaction.commit();
    }
}
```

but this has an error:

```
Require: android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager
Found: android.app.FragmentManager
```

i already use

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

but not true,idk why and how to fix that. pls help me. thanks alots

Comment: You are import the android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager and removed the android.app.FragmentManager package.

Comment: use `FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();` and in your imports have only `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`

Comment: I did not found any lines like: android.app.FragmentManager;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend `AppCompatActivity` in place of `Activity`and then  `getSupportFragmentManager()` will work.

Then you can directly call getSupportFragmentManager without application context.

Comment: please check updated answer, just change activity to AppCompatActivity

Comment: thanks man. i will get new project with AppCompat and this work